# How do I convert this pseudo-code and what list do I need for the formula

Tags: python, algorithm, pseudocode

I've been given a computing assignment to create randomly generate game levels using pseudo-code and algorithms. The map must be printed using #'s and spaces and cells with fewer than 3 neighbors die. But we have been told to work it out without covering either and it's safe to say I have no idea what I'm doing. Any help would be appreciated...

Here's the whole code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random

def create_random_map(height, width):
  map = []
  for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        map.append( bool(random.randint(0,1)) )

  return map

def apply_cellular_automaton(map, height, width, born, survive):
   return map

def draw_map(map, height, width):
  pass

height = 45
width = 79

map = create_random_map(height, width)

for i in range(5):
  map = apply_cellular_automaton(map, height, width, [6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

for i in range(3):
  map = apply_cellular_automaton(map, height, width, [5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8])


draw_map(map, height, width)
```

Pseudo-code I have been given

```
 PROCEDURE draw_map(map, height, width)
    FOR EACH grid row
            CREATE AN EMPTY row
            FOR EACH cell in row
                    IF cell IS alive
                            ADD ‘#’ TO row
                    ELSE
                            ADD ‘ ‘ TO row
            PRINT row
```

Formula example I have been given

```
i = (y * width) + x 61 = (7 * 8) + 5
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Thanks for posting the code you have so far! Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what you're asking, for instance, I don't know what "work it out without covering either" means. Further, your code appears to have several indentation errors, so can you please correct those?

Comment: Also you should ask a specific question. The purpose of an exercise is to try and learn, not letting others do the work. Have you tried implementing any part of the procedure? If so please post this code and explain your problems.

Comment: @Nabla I need to know how i would go about implementing the pseudo code and the formula. I've attempted using for and while loops and have got no where

Comment: @user3157254 Then please edit your question, insert the code you have and explain what you tried and why. If you don't have anything to present then try working the pseudo-code line by line.

Comment: You need to write the functions `create_random_map` and so on, then test them in a while or for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might first work out a viable structure for map.
map needs to be a two dimensional structure. One way of doing that is to make map a list-of-lists i.e. a list of rows where each rows elements are column of that row. See [Create a two-dimensional array at runtime](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Create_a_two-dimensional_array_at_runtime) on the Rosetta Code site.

Next populate an array and try and turn your draw_map pseudo-code into proper Python around your implementation of a 2D array.